# Change a script to check remaining space of a drive

Tags: vbscript

I currently have this VBScript, which checks the size of a folder, then deletes files (oldest first) until a threshold is reached.

```
Option Explicit
'use next line for production
On Error Resume Next 
'use next line for debugging
'On Error GoTo 0

Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName
Dim objFSO, strOldestFile, dtmOldestDate, strFolder, oFolder, intFolderSize

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dtmOldestDate = Now
strFolder     = "C:\Users\PLEX\Downloads\Torrent\"
strOldestFile = "" 
Set oFolder   = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

intFolderSize = Int(((oFolder.Size / 1024) / 1024) / 1024)

Do While intFolderSize >= 110
  strOldestFile = ""
  dtmOldestDate = Now

  FindOldestFile oFolder

  'WScript.Echo strOldestFile
  objFSO.DeleteFile strOldestFile, True
  strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & dtmOldestDate & vbTab & strOldestFile

  intFolderSize = Int(((oFolder.Size / 1024) / 1024) / 1024)
Loop

'WScript.Echo strResult
WScript.Quit

Sub FindOldestFile(objFolder)
  Dim objFile, colFiles, colFolders, strFile, dtmFileDate
  'find oldest file
  Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
  For Each objFile In colFiles
    strFile = objFile.Path
    dtmFileDate = objFile.DateCreated
    If dtmFileDate < dtmOldestDate Then
      dtmOldestDate = dtmFileDate
      strOldestFile = strFile
    End If
  Next
  'recurse subfolders
  Set colFolders = objFolder.SubFolders
  For Each objFile In colFolders
    FindOldestFile objFile
  Next
End Sub
```

Currently this script will:

1. Check the capacity of folder A including all subfolders.
2. Delete files (oldest first) from folder A and subfolders until a threshold is reached (in this case, 110GB)

I'd like to modify the script to do this:

1. Check the capacity of folder A including all subfolders.
2. Delete files (oldest first) from folder B (which is a subfolder of folder A) and subfolders until a threshold is reached.

For example, is it possible to get this script to check the used capacity of the entire C: drive and delete the oldest files from `C:\Users\PLEX\Downloads\Torrent\` when there is less than 5% remaining on C:?

---

**Edit:** I already had full access, and fixed the error by changing `C:\` to `C:` . I also changed `C:\Users\PLEX\Desktop\New Folder` to `\Users\PLEX\Desktop\New Folder` and am now getting no errors. The only problem is that `IntFolderSize` still shows the size of my subfolder, not the root. I've confirmed that by using `Wscript.Echo intfoldersize`. My current script is below. How can I get `IntFolderSize` to show the used size of the root?

```
option explicit
'use next line for production
'On Error Resume Next 
'use next line for debugging
'On Error GoTo 0

Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName
Dim objFSO, strOldestFile, dtmOldestDate, strFolder, oFolder, intFolderSize
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    dtmOldestDate = Now
    strFolder = "C:"
    strOldestFile = "" 
Set oFolder = objFSO.GetFolder( strFolder)

intFolderSize = Int(((oFolder.Size / 1024) / 1024) / 1024)

Wscript.Echo intfoldersize

Do While intFolderSize >= 70
  strOldestFile = ""
  dtmOldestDate = Now

FindOldestFile objFSO.GetFolder(objFSO.BuildPath(strFolder,"\Users\PLEX\Desktop\New Folder\"))

'wscript.echo strOldestFile
  objFSO.DeleteFile strOldestFile, True
  strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & dtmOldestDate & vbTab & strOldestFile 

  intFolderSize = Int(((oFolder.Size / 1024) / 1024) / 1024)

Loop

'Wscript.Echo strResult
Wscript.Quit

Sub FindOldestFile( objFolder)
  Dim objFile, colFiles, colFolders, strFile, dtmFileDate
  ' find oldest file
  Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
  For Each objFile in colFiles
    strFile = objFile.Path
    dtmFileDate = objFile.DateCreated
    If dtmFileDate < dtmOldestDate Then
      dtmOldestDate = dtmFileDate
      strOldestFile = strFile
    End If
  Next
  ' recurse subfolders
  Set colFolders = objFolder.SubFolders
  For Each objFile in colFolders
    FindOldestFile objFile
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
FindOldestFile oFolder
```

into

```
FindOldestFile objFSO.GetFolder(objFSO.BuildPath(strFolder, "sub\folder"))
```

where `strFolder` is your root folder and `"sub\folder"` the relative path to the subfolder below that root folder.

---

**Edit:** Note that the `oFolder.Size` property will raise an error unless you have access to every single file and folder below `oFolder`. If you want to check the free diskspace on the volume anyway, you may be better off using WMI for that and using `oFolder` strictly for the folder you want to delete from:

```
strFolder   = "C:\Users\PLEX\Desktop\New folder"
Set oFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

threshold = ...    'desired minimum free diskspace in byte

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume WHERE DriveLetter='C:'"

Do While wmi.ExecQuery(qry).ItemIndex(0).FreeSpace < threshold
  ...
  FindOldestFile oFolder
  ...
Loop
```

Comment: [This is what my script looks like now.](http://pastebin.com/AGQ3mmgS) I'm getting an accessed denied error on line 16 `intFolderSize = Int(((oFolder.Size / 1024) / 1024) / 1024)`. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: `"sub\folder"` must be relative to the root folder, not an absolute path, and you must have full access to everything below the root folder for `.Size` to work.

Comment: I already had full access, and fixed the error by changing `C:\ ` to `C:` . I also changed `C:\Users\PLEX\Desktop\New Folder` to `\Users\PLEX\Desktop\New Folder` and am now getting no errors. The only problem is that `IntFolderSize` still shows the size of my subfolder, not the root. I've confirmed that by using `Wscript.Echo intfoldersize`.

[My current script can be found here.](http://pastebin.com/NbrEWu1g) How can I get `IntFolderSize` to show the used size of the root?

Comment: @Cameron `.GetFolder("C:")` without the trailing backslash after the colon gives you the current directory on the given drive, which is not necessarily the root folder (check with `WScript.Echo oFolder.Path`). On any modern Windows system you don't have full access to everything on C:, not even as an administrator, so `.GetFolder("C:\").Size` should raise an error. Use the approach outlined in my answer.